# Getting notified of newly created files on mac os?

Tags: windows, macos, macos-sierra, explorer, finder

Is there a way I can write a mac os app that gets notified when there's a new file of a certain file type (lets say a .jpg file) created somewhere on the system?

Does finder maybe have some mechanics in place that gets notified about new files that I can pull from?

The thing I want to achieve is an app that whenever the user creates a file of a certain file type asks the user if she wants to upload it or share it etc.

Also interested if, and if so, how it's possible to achieve this in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `File System Events` API, `FSEvents`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html